# geth gets stuck at IPC endpoint opened

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu

So I just [FEB 12, 2018] spun up an Ubuntu 16.04 VM and installed geth using the ppa.

```
geth version
```

> Geth
>   Version: 1.7.3-stable
>   Git Commit: 4bb3c89d44e372e6a9ab85a8be0c9345265c763a
>   Architecture: amd64
>   Protocol Versions: [63 62]
>   Network Id: 1
>   Go Version: go1.9
>   Operating System: linux
>   GOPATH=
>   GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.9

Now I would like to connect to testnet.  My internet research claims I should be able to do

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "fast"
```

or

```
geth --testnet --rpc --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --syncmode "fast" --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545
```

Both commands result in the same...

> WARN [02-12|12:13:49] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-amd64/go1.9
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/parallels/.ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO:  DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10 Byzantium: 1700000 Engine: ethash}"
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/home/parallels/.ethereum/testnet/geth/ethash count=3
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/home/parallels/.ethash                       count=2
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:49] Starting P2P networking
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:51] UDP listener up                          self=enode://399e42ef589c6202d31e64509432030b11ed642d261fa337811cb3f7838f606db47ffb91ef91dc464923450f55773f5ace698be2035a95dcaaf77f9843cf4b9b@[::]:30303
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:51] HTTP endpoint opened: http://0.0.0.0:8545 
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:51] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://399e42ef589c6202d31e64509432030b11ed642d261fa337811cb3f7838f606db47ffb91ef91dc464923450f55773f5ace698be2035a95dcaaf77f9843cf4b9b@[::]:30303
>   INFO [02-12|12:13:51] IPC endpoint opened: /home/parallels/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc

It appears to be stuck on `IPC endpoint opened`.  I am both a linux newbie and an ethereum newbie.  Just trying to learn.  I don't know where to start looking for what is wrong.  Can you help me get this going?

Update:
After an hour and a half there's a new message

> INFO [02-12|13:44:02] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a networking question.
I had to port forward TCP and UDP ports 30303 on the router to my VM's IP address.

After doing that and restarting geth, the chain began to synchronize almost immediately.

Comment: I've tryied `geth` for couple weeks. It simply doesnt work as expected. It synced for the first time with `fast` param. And the, after couple days began to lag from chain again. I tried everyhning. The only way it worked was to remove db and start syncing over. Each time it was hanging on sync noumerous times. Finally i switched to `parity` - had no troubles with syncing at all. And it has same rpc interfaces, so dont waste your tie on geth.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much was also having the same issue when I tried to run geth for the first time on my system. I applied what is suggested above, i.e. port forward TCP and UDP ports 30303 on the router. I am using a Huawei B525 router and did the following: settings->security->special applications-> special applications list

Name: geth; status: on; trigger port: 30303; trigger protocol:TCP; open protocol: UDP; open port 30303; then click add, ok, apply.

Then went cmd prompt run geth and it did run past IPC endpoint open!

Thanks!